# Ruby on Rails send_file, code in controller action running twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm running into a weird issue with user downloadable files, the file is downloading properly, but other code in the controller action is executing twice.  I'm using CarrierWave, which is mounted on a Document model at .file.

I want users to be able to click this link to download the file:

```
<%= link_to document.file.file.filename, document_path(document)  %>
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
  def show
    document = Document.find(params[:id])

    # Track this download
    CourseDownload.create(course: document.course, user: current_user)   

    # Download the file
    send_file 'public' + document.file.url.to_s
  end
```

When I click the link, the file downloads, but 2 CourseDownload records are created.  In the logs it looks like the GET request is happening twice:

```
Started GET "/documents/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-17 18:12:47 -0400
Processing by DocumentsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Document Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'xxx' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
public/uploads/document/file/1/bootstrap-3.0.0.zip
Sent file public/uploads/document/file/1/bootstrap-3.0.0.zip (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/documents/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-17 18:12:47 -0400
Processing by DocumentsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Document Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'xxx' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
public/uploads/document/file/1/bootstrap-3.0.0.zip
Sent file public/uploads/document/file/1/bootstrap-3.0.0.zip (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In which view is the link_to ?  I'm wondering if you have it in the show.html, which could mean you're loading the page initially to show the link, and reloading the page when the link is clicked... so really executing the action twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue ended up being caused by a [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/182) gotcha.

Resolved with:

```
<%= link_to document.file.file.filename, document_path(document), 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>
```